# setting focus on top of scrollview after an action happens android

Tags: android, scrollview

In my app I am making some computations. The whole layout is inside a Scrollview.

The result is being shown on top. Xml is like that:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back2back"
    >


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="526dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back4"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nothing"
        android:layout_width="181dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

        rest of the xml
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

So I want when pressing the calculate button the focus of the screen to be set to the top of my page (or to be more specific in the upper textview) so the user will be able to see a result. I searched in SO but I have not found something similar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand your question, simply call:

```
scrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

in your calculation Button's OnClickListener.